i18.resolvedLanguage is undefined
When i intialise i18 using createInstance()
i18n.resolvedLanguage is coming as undefined
But when i direcly use i18 without instance, it works fine
What is wrong in this?
const i18Instance = i18n.createInstance();

i18Instance
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(I18nextBrowserLanguageDetector)
  .init({
    detection: {
      order: ['navigator'],
    },
    resources,
    debug: true,
    fallbackLng: 'de',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
      format: (value, format, lng) => {
        if (format === 'capitalize') {
          const firstLetter = value.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase(lng);
          return firstLetter + value.slice(1);
        }
        //no formating present atm
        return value;
      },
    },
    returnNull: false,
  });

export default i18Instance;

When i try to i18next.resolvedLanguage inside child components, getting undefined
 import i18next from 'i18next';
 console.log('log..', i18next.resolvedLanguage);  //undefined

